# C# Silverlight Lync API

Tags: c#, silverlight, lync

We are looking into creating a custom silverlight lync presence indicator on our .net website.

The control will display all users in an online course.

The issue is that the users might not be among the session user's contacts.

How do I get around this or is there a way to add a contact to someones contact list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the contactlist control.